# icon is not coming to adjacent to text in android Tablayout.

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am trying to build TabLayout, with text and icon(adjacent to each other). 
But icon is coming above the text . 
I am doing this to add icons :

```
   private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.email_id_icon);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.email_id_icon);
}
```

this is my full code. Please tell me what am I doing wrong ?

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vets_listing);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();
}

private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.email_id_icon);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.email_id_icon);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new WalkInFragment(),"Walk in");
    adapter.addFragment(new HomeVisitFragment(),"Home Visit");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try following link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370081/how-to-set-icon-next-to-text-in-tablayout

Comment: Or you can try this as well : http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: I followed android Hive's tutorial only . But the result was not as expected. 
Icon was on top of text instead of being adjacent to it.

Comment: How many tabs you are having?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom tab layout and position your icon as per your wish.
Here is a sample code on how you can do it.

Create a custom_tab.xml layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
android:textSize="15sp"
/>
```

Change your setup icon method to this

```
private void setupTabIcons() {
TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tabOne.setText("ONE");
tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float, 0, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tabTwo.setText("TWO");
tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.R.drawable.checkbox_on_background, 0, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tabThree.setText("THREE");
tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float, 0, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);
```

}

This will do it. Here is a github link to the implementation of the custom tab layout.
[Tab with icons](https://github.com/mayankkussh/tabWithIcons)